# remote desktop vnc on Debian VPS

Tags: debian, vnc, mate-desktop

I have a Debian 8 VPS which I installed MATE desktop environment using the `tasksel` command.

I then installed a VNC server using

```
apt-get install vnc4server
```

but when I use realvnc to connect I get the following message

> The connection was refused by the host computer

Any pointers as what I need to do in order to connect using vnc?

Comment: Hi,  opening a VNC port for the Internet-at-large is a terrible security practice. That said, go to the web interface of the VPS provider and open 5900/TCP in their firewall interface at your own risk. I´d suggest to add to this and future posts the name of that VPS provider, there are often specific issues tied to them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually *run* the vncserver - it does not start automatically.

And if by any chance you want to share your existing session, vncserver is not the right tool - you want `x11vnc` or `vino` for that.

Comment: @Arya: and if you nevertheless use vnc4server, chose a non existent display to avoid errors.